# How to rearrange the array element from 0th index in the sequence to end?

Tags: php, arrays

How to rearrange the array element from 0th index in the sequence to end in PHP?

> **UPDATED**

I have an array:

```
$input =array{ 
                              2 => '13234390',
                              4 => '12345290',
                              5 => '21322210' 
                              }
```

now I want this array to be rearranged as

```
$input =array{ 
                              0 => '13234390',
                              1 => '12345290',
                              2 => '21322210' 
                              }
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With

- [`array_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) returns all the values from the input array and indexes numerically the array.

Example:

```
$array = array_values($input);
```

Comment: I s there any other way to do it... are u actually getting me.. I want rearrange the same array in proper sequence...

Comment: @OMThe well, yes. You could do `usort($input, function() { return 1; });` which would not create a copy of the array, but that's about 3 to 4 times slower.

Comment: I used the array_values() but but arranged my values in ascending order.. i dont want the order of values to be changed